# Build composed C# Linq Where with multiple lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, expression, predicate

I have the following error when try to build an OR expression composed with another two expressions:

`The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'System.Func'2[Alarm,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func'2[Alarm,System.Boolean]'.`

What I want to do is combine two Expression methods in a third method with OR operator, as follows:

```
//First expression method
private static Expression<Func<Alarm, bool>> _unacknowledged() 
{
    return alarm => alarm.AcknowledgeDate == null;
}

//Second expression method
private static Expression<Func<Alarm, bool>> _occurring()
{
    return alarm => alarm.OccurrenceFinalDate == null;
}

//Third expression method (that combines the above)
private Expression<Func<Alarm, bool>> _unacknowledgedOrOccurring()
{
    //This is where exception is raised
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Alarm, bool>>(
        Expression.Or(_unacknowledged(), _occurring())
    );

    return expr;
}
```

The expected practical clause that I want using the `_unacknowledgedOrOccurring()` call must be similar to this:

```
alarmList.Where(alarm => 
    alarm.AcknowledgeDate == null ||
    alarm.OccurrenceFinalDate == null
)
```

It's possible to do this? What exactly I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`Expression.Or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.or?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Or_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_) is the bitwise OR operator. You need [`Expression.OrElse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.orelse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Yes, I agree with the "duplicate" flag. Unfortunately had not found it previously in searchings. I'll mark this as solved with another referred question. Thanks to all that help in any way.

Answer (score 0):

like @NetMage pointed out, you need `Expression.OrElse` instead of OR, beside that what's your missing is the your lambda expression required a paremeter list which also the  target instance to be invoked on by your `_unacknowledged` and `_occurring`.

```
//Third expression method (that combines the above)
private static Expression<Func<Alarm, bool>> _unacknowledgedOrOccurring()
{       
    var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Alarm));
    var or = Expression.OrElse(Expression.Invoke(_unacknowledged(), target), Expression.Invoke(_occurring(), target));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Alarm, bool>>(or, target);
}
```

Comment: I would be tempted to re-write the bodies of the two expressions to use a new parameter, and avoid the `Invoke`.